# Maximum length of a line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I wonder whether it is possible to work out the maximum length per line in Notepad++ and highlight only those lines exceeding a certain threshold. I know there is a way to do it indirectly by customising the vertical edge, but it would not be feasible if you have a long document to scroll.

Thanks,

I.

Comment: What do you mean by "work out the maximum length per line"?

Comment: @BoltClock, see below answer. I meant the number of characters per line, according to a set threshold.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can look for lines longer than a given threshold as follows:

Edit -> Find -> Select "Regular expression" in "Search Mode", look for `.{x,}` where `x` is your desired threshold (e.g. `.{15,}` to look for lines that are 15 characters or longer).

`.` is a wild-card and `{x,}` means `x` or more of what appears before it, so `.{x,}` means `x` or more of any combination of characters.

Also make sure that the `. matches newline` option is **not** checked, otherwise it won't work.

I'm not sure if this helps, but that's about as much as you can do only using Notepad++.